# Skype doesn't see my webcam

Tags: skype, webcam, apparmor

I've got Logitech C270 (/dev/video0) that is seen by Cheese in Xubuntu 14.04, but Skype doesn't recognize it. What can I do? Should I blame my [apparmor profile](http://pastebin.com/Mmvs0UGc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `/{run,dev}/shm/pulse-shm` permissions to `mrw,`

```
/{run,dev}/shm/pulse-shm* mrw,
```

(then `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.skype`)

The profile I use: http://pastebin.com/a03tnZbx

Comment: **What** are you suggesting to do **where** and **how**?.

Comment: I've just switched from my profile to yours and it started working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Skype 4.2 (from the Ubuntu Software Center) and installing the latest version (4.3) from skype.com (I selected Ubuntu 12.04 as distribution) worked for me

alex

Comment: I've installed it a week ago, but it didn't help.